How can one execute a CodeAction programmatically from a VSCode extension?
Is it possible to execute another extension's code action programmatically from my VSCode extension? Specifically I need to run the resolveCodeAction of the code action provider before executing, which seems to be what VSCode does before running a Quick Fix.
Most posts that I have seen outline something like this:
const diagnostics = vscode.languages.getDiagnostics(document.uri);

for (const diagnostic of diagnostics) {
  const { range } = diagnostic;
                
  // Get the quick fixes for the current diagnostic
  const codeActions = await vscode.commands.executeCommand<vscode.CodeAction[]>(
    'vscode.executeCodeActionProvider',
    document.uri,
    range,
    vscode.CodeActionKind.QuickFix.value
  );

  if (codeActions && codeActions.length > 0) {
    // Apply the first quick fix
    await vscode.commands.executeCommand(
      codeActions[0].command.command, 
      ...codeActions[0].command.arguments
    );
  }
}

However, through experimentation it seems that vscode.executeCodeActionProvider only runs the provideCodeAction step of the interface, and not the resolveCodeAction step for the resolved actions.
To be concrete, I am trying to run the bundled typescript-language-features extensions "_typescript.applyFixAllCodeAction".
Is there a preferred way to execute CodeActions to emulate the way VSCode handles them internally?
EDIT: this is not a duplicate of 'Add all missing imports' shortcut, I am not asking how to run this action as VSCode user, I am asking how to do it programmatically as a VSCode extension author.

I reopened it - sorry for the noise.

I actually found the answer to this in the VSCode docs. There is a final optional parameter you can add which is the number of code actions returned you want to have resolved. So for instance:
const codeActions = await vscode.commands.executeCommand<vscode.CodeAction[]>(
    'vscode.executeCodeActionProvider',
    document.uri,
    range,
    vscode.CodeActionKind.QuickFix.value,
    7
  );

will run the appropriate resolveCodeAction method for the first 7 results.
It's not perfect but it is workable.

Nice find!  That arg is optional, I wonder what the default is?

From my experimentation, I think the default is 0.
